# What does the ! operator mean in Lambda/LINQ expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

What is the ! operator right after Title?

movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title!.Contains(searchString));

Comment: It's the [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving), telling the compiler we are sure that `s.Title` is not `null` even if it might think it is. There is no effect on the LINQ query itself.

Comment: Oh well, I know that is the case when passing over arguments to a method, but I never saw this working with a LINQ query before. Thanks!